# How can I split the array of objects based on the array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Array of objects is :

[ { seriesObject: { data:[a1, a2, a3, .... a1000] } } ]

and I want to convert this into 10 different array objects

i.e

[ { seriesObject:{ data:[a1, a2, a3, .... a1000] } ] // 1st chunk

[ { seriesObject:{ data:[a1, a2, a3, .... a1000] } ] // 2nd chunk

[ { seriesObject:{ data:[a1, a2, a3, .... a1000] } ] // ...

[ { seriesObject:{ data:[a1, a2, a3, .... a1000] } ] // 10th chunk

Comment: _I want to convert this into..._ What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: your `array of objects` isn't correct.  you can't have keys in an array

Comment: `[ ]` means an array and `{ }` means an object.  Even though an array is an object, `[ seriesObject: { data:[10000] } ]` is not the proper way to represent an array.  Could you make a better representation maybe like {seriesObject: { data: [a0,a1, ..., a9999] }}

Comment: Which api do you need this for in Highcharts?

Comment: [Bar chart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cbar%3E).

Answer (score 1):

I will supposed that the object is like this { data: [a0,a1, ..., a9999] }.

```js
function partition (obj, n) {
  var count = obj.data.length, len = count/n;
  var arr = [];
  for(var k = 0; k < count; ) {
    var new_obj = {"data":[]};
    for (var j = 0 ; k < count && j < len; ++j, ++k) {
      new_obj.data.push(obj.data[k]);
    }
    arr.push(new_obj);
  }
  return arr;
}

var o = {"data":[]};
for(var k = 0; k < 10000; ++k) {
  o.data.push(k);
}

console.log( partition(o, 10) );
```

Comment: ^^ is what I want @dominique-fortin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want:

```js
var arr = [{data:[]},{data:[]},{data:[]}];
var arrays = {}
for(var i in arr){
arrays[i] = arr[i];
}
console.log(arrays);
```

**- Edit 1:**

Is this what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/fqqz8vjc/3/

Comment: `var arrays = {}` ???  Also `[{data1:[]},{data2:[]},{data3:[]}];` would be a problem because you would have to add a number to the property name `data` in order to automate the access the data.

Comment: It's a different result. With my sketch they aren't in an array but all divided into individual arrays indexed into an object ^^

Comment: I'm going to pass this chucked object to Highcharts` `series` attribute. so changing the `data` to `data1`, `data2` would not work with Highcharts.

Comment: Man the name of the arrays was an example, it still works with the same name! I just edited the question to show you, in this way you can access them like they are in an array but they still aren't, so if you want the first array you do arrays[0] etc..

Comment: Trying to achieve this behaviour [JSFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqqz8vjc/). But since my `data` is inside an object, I want to chuck the `data` into `n` number of chucks so that it does not exceed [`turboThreshold`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.turboThreshold).

Comment: Try my jsfiddle, you will see the result in your console log, let me know if this is what you wanted to do

Comment: @being_jai Your jsfiddle looks fine.  What are you looking for? Be more descriptive.